# Dealing with constants inside functions

Tags: c, system, constants, c-preprocessor

I want to define a constant if something is true, and use its value inside a "system("");

For example:

```
#ifdef __unix__
#   define CLRSCR clear
#elif defined _WIN32
#   define CLRSCR cls
#endif


int main(){
    system("CLRSCR"); //use its value here.
}
```

I know there is `clrscr();` in conio.h/conio2.h but this is just an example. And when I try to launch it, it says `cls` is not declared, or that CLRSCR is not a internal command (bash)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constant is an *identifier*, not a *string literal* (string literals have double quotes around them; identifiers do not).

Constant value, on the other hand, is a string literal, not an identifier. You need to switch it around like this:

```
#ifdef __unix__
#   define CLRSCR "clear"
#elif defined _WIN32
#   define CLRSCR "cls"
#endif


int main(){
    system(CLRSCR); //use its value here.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need this:

```
#ifdef __unix__
   #define CLRSCR "clear"
#elif defined _WIN32
   #define CLRSCR "cls"
#endif


system(CLRSCR); //use its value here.
```